# Put a button inside the <a></a> tag using pug.js

Tags: html, node.js, pug

this is my expected result:

```
<a>
    <button class="btn btn-tomato mx-auto" type="button" style="width:50%; white-space: normal; opacity:0.8;">Button text</button>  
</a>
```

So I wrote my pug like this:

```
a
    button.btn.btn-tomato.mx-auto(type='button', style='width:50%; white-space: normal; opacity:0.8')
```

However, the result is like this:

```
<a></a>
<button class="btn btn-tomato mx-auto" type="button" style="width:50%; white-space: normal; opacity:0.8;">Button text</button>
```

The `<button>` is not in the `<a>`. Would you please tell me how to fix that? thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HTML *forbids* buttons from appearing inside anchors.

- If you want a link, use an `<a>`.
- If you want to submit a form, use a `<button>`.
- If you want something to trigger JavaScript from and cannot write [Unobtrusive JS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript), then use a `<button type="button">`.

Then apply CSS to make it look the way you want.